# How do I remove duplicated SNPs using PLink?

Tags: bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

I am working with [PLINK](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/) to analyse genome-wide data.

Does anyone know how to remove duplicated SNPs?

Comment: Wouldn't that be --exclude duplicateSNPs.txt? Check out the unix utility uniq for a solution to your problem.

Comment: [Should the plink tag be used for the genome tool or for the PuTTY (SSH) command line tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178289/146482)

Comment: Duplicate by rsID or duplicate by position by the way?

Answer (score 5):

In PLINK 1.9, use `--list-duplicate-vars suppress-first`, which will list duplicates, and remove one (the first one), leaving the other intact. I've know this to slip up though.

Instead of using `--exclude` as Davy suggested, you can also use `--extract`, keeping rather than getting rid of a list of SNPs. There's an easy method on any Unix based system (assuming your data are in PED/MAP format and cut up by chromossome):

```
for i in {1..22}; do
  cat yourfile_chr${i}.map | grep "$i" | cut -f -4 | uniq | cut -f -2 | keepers_chr${i}.txt;
done
```

This will create a `keepers_chr.txt` file with SNP IDs for SNPs at unique locations. Then run PLINK feeding it your original file(s) and use `--extract keepers_chr`, with `--make-bed --out unique_file`

Answer (score 3):

There is no command to do it automatically that I am aware of, but the way I have done it in the past is to get a list of SNPs that are duplicated, change the duplicates to rs1001.dup for example, then run `--update-allele --update-name` and then create a list of the duplicates, so all the entries will have `.dup` at the end of their names, and then run `--extract duplicateSNPs.txt --make-bed --out yourfilename.dups.removed`

Getting a list of SNPs that are duplicated shouldn't be too hard if you are familiar with R. Sorry to give you a "well just learn X!!!" answer

Answer (score 2):

A couple of others ideas that might be of help/interest:

1. You can also remove vcf duplicates using bcftools with the command `bcftools norm -D, --remove-duplicates` bcftools documentation can be found at https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html
2. In the spirit of also just using Unix to remove duplicates, I've previously used the following (input is a compressed vcf file) `gunzip -c  input.vcf.gz | grep "^[^##]" | cut -f3 | sort | uniq -d > plink.dupvar` plink.dupvar is the filename the PLINK program looks for when performing the duplication removal step.

Answer (score 0):

With R is easier, although you have to use a TPED file. Once you manage to get a TPED file just copy and paste this into a R console:

```
a = read.table("yourfile.TPED",sep = " ",header=FALSE)
b = a[!duplicated(a$V2),]
write.table(b,file="newfile.TPED",sep=" ",quote = FALSE,col.names = FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

The `newfile.TPED` without duplicates will apper in the R working directory.
HINT: you can change the `yourfile.TPED` and `newfile.TPED` part of the script for the actual name of you file.